# Help w/ Countertop Dishwasher Connection/Adapter

Tags: faucet, dishwasher, connectors, adapter

I have a countertop dishwasher that needs to be hooked into my faucet, but the major obstacle is that my faucet is a pull-out spray head. I can pop the bottom of the spray head off to reveal the aerator underneath and I've purchased [an adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WFFZ2BL) to try to connect the faucet aerator to the to dishwasher water intake, but the adapter doesn't fit into faucet aerator and I've been struggling to figure out the sizing to find a smaller version. Any guidance on parts, sizing, and assembly for a viable connection would be much appreciated.

But more generally it would be great to have more advice about the best way to solve this problem generally. I read [this blog post](https://kilbasar.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/connecting-a-portable-dishwasher-to-a-pull-down-faucet-hose/) with one suggestion, but it just seems to janky too be practical. Any other suggestions?

**Countertop Dishwasher:**
[image: Dishwasher]

**Pull-Out Spray Head Faucet:**
[image: Pull-Out Spray Head Faucet]

**The pull down head with the black top taken off:**
[image]

**The other side of the black top that screws into the head plus a washer that sits in between:**
[image]

**Water Connection into Dishwasher:**
[image: Water Connection into Dishwasher]
[image: Water Connection into Dishwasher]

**Aerator that came with Dishwasher:**
[image: Aerator that came with Dishwasher]

**Adapter in Dishwasher Hookup (15/16"-27 outside threads + 55/64"-27 inside threads):**
[image: Adapter in Dishwasher Hookup]

Comment: With plumbing sometimes you end up with janky solutions. Surprising that nobody offers an adapter.

Comment: It would be good to [edit] in the suggestion from "this one article" in case the link dies.

Comment: How do you feel about replacing your faucet?

Comment: Or adding a separate tap (under the counter?) that the dishwasher could connect to?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see, you are going to have to replace the faucet. You could look again and see if you can disconnect the whole end of the pulldown from the hose and go from there. Otherwise, get a non pulldown faucet and the adaptor will just screw on. Had one setup that way for years.

Just recently remodeled and added a second faucet just for the dishwasher, so the main could be a pulldown.

Best of luck.

Comment: Why not just put in an adapter from the faucet aerator to the thread size for the dishwasher connection? Seems a whole lot easier and far less expensive than adding a second faucet to a kitchen sink...

Answer (score 0):

Howabout one more suggestion.

What do you think about this suggestion?

Take the sprayhead to your local hardware store and there you will find the solution.  A fitting that you will do the job, one you can deal with.

The worse thing to do is to buy an adapter and then find out that you got wrong stuff.  You learned that lesson already.

Okay take care.

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion I have is to hook that device to a sink elsewhere in the house.

Otherwise, yes, take the two pieces you want to fit to each other to a hardware store and look in the plumbing adapters rack. There should be some object there, or combination of objects, that will let you make this connection.

Otherwise... replace this tap with a traditional one, or install a second tap just for the dishwasher thing, or retire the toy dishwasher in favor of a real one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to replace the faucet as suggested in another answer, but it's possible you could just replace the pullout spray head.

In the middle of your spray head there is a small screen.   On some spray heads but not yours, that screen is screwed into the head using the same threading as you have on your dishwasher adaptor.  You could remove the screen and screw in your adaptor.

If you can find a head like that, and if it is adaptable to your existing pullout hose and if its base fits snugly in your existing faucet arm ... that'll work.

It will still look janky.  Maybe you could install a second small faucet into the countertop just for the dishwasher, or just a hose connection without a faucet, and leave it permanently connected.